# Access data marked as Content

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I am writing a WPF client application that contains several JSON files that are used to load the ComboBoxes and ListBoxes with data strings.

While writing, I simply used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get the root and navigate to the JSON files from there.

Now, the issue is I am at the point where I am ready to publish, but the data will no longer load.

I have the data files all marked "Copy Always" and as "Content" in the build action. I assume the data files are copied to a different location during publish, but I do not know where. I would like them to be copied to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder if possible, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Have you checked your appdata folder on your local system. You can use the command %appdata% to access that folder directly. If you don't see it make sure that it is not hidden.

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have asked the question wrong. I have the appdata folder, what I am trying to understand is where files marked "Copy Always" and "Context" are published to, and then the proper way to copy them to the appdata/local directory.